# Commit failed in svn due to unknown reason

Tags: svn, repository, commit, command-prompt

I tried to commit but and error appeared. I neither know what caused it nor how to fix it. Please help.

here is the error message:

```
svn: E175008: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E175008: At least one property change failed; repository is unchanged
svn: E175002: The PROPPATCH request returned invalid XML in the response: XML parse error at line 7: invalid element name
```

I am using the command prompt to commit. How I am supposed to cope with that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Find which properties you've changed, see if any of the property values are corrupt or otherwise malformed or are values that would not be valid when set in an XML message and remove them.

Alternatively it could be a standard property such as commit message, people have noticed this in the past when entering a multiline comment (ie with 'bad' line ending characters). Try a shorter log message.

Comment: Well in my case the log message isn't big, but how to find those properties? By saying properties do you mean the files?